# Existance of limit for value of $a$

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider the limit

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} x^a \left ( \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^\frac{2}{7} - x^\frac{2}{7} \right ) $$

Does there exist a value for $a$ for which the limit exists, and it's value is different from $0$ and $\infty$. I was able to confirm through trial that for $a = \frac{12}{7} $ the condition listed is satisfied.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem, I've tried to use LHopital's but that didn't work and got very messy quickly.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is $12/7$. In fact, write
$$
(x+1/x)^{2/7}-x^{2/7}=x^{2/7}[(1+x^{-2})^{2/7}-1].
$$
In general when $c>0$ we have $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(1+z)^c-1}{z}=c$ by l'Hosptal. So
$$
x^{\frac{12}{7}}[(x+1/x)^{2/7}-x^{2/7}]=x^{\frac{12}{7}}x^{2/7}\frac{(1+x^{-2})^{2/7}-1}{x^{-2}}x^{-2}=\frac{(1+x^{-2})^{2/7}-1}{x^{-2}}\to \frac 27.
$$

Comment: I didn't think about that... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It could be interesting to make the problem more generat
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^a \left ( \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^b - x^b \right )$$
$$ \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^b - x^b =x^b\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^b-1\right)=x^b \left(\frac{b}{x^2}+\frac{(b-1) b}{2
   x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)\right)$$

So, for large values of $x$
$$x^a \left ( \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^b - x^b \right )\sim b x^{a+b-2}$$ which, for a finite limit (which will be $b$), requiers $a=2-b$